# normal reverse hazard rate

Tags: calculus, probability, limits, statistics, normal-distribution

Let
$$h(x)=\frac{\phi(x)}{\Phi(x)}$$

where $\phi$ and $\Phi$ are PDF and CDF of standard normal distribution.

Can we tell that 
$$h'(x)\geq -1$$ 
for all $x\in (-\infty,+\infty)$ and 
$$x+h(x)\geq 0$$
for all $x\in (-\infty,+\infty)$ ?

Comment: The second inequality is easy to show. Define $g(x) := \phi(x) + x \Phi(x)$. $g \to 0$ as $x \to -\infty$, and $g' = \Phi(x) \ge 0$ (using the fact that $\phi' = -x\phi(x)$) does the job. No clue on the first, will add an  answer if I figure it out. Meanwhile, I suggest that you add what you have tried to the question in order to both guide further attempts, and prevent your question from being closed as lacking sufficient details.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $h'(x)+1=\frac{\phi(z)}{\Phi(x)^2}f(x)$, where $f(x)=\frac{\phi'(x)}{\phi(x)}\Phi(x)-\phi(x)+\frac{\Phi(x)^2}{\phi(x)}$.

Also knowing that $\phi'(x)=-x\phi(x)$, we can show that $f'(x)=\Phi(x)\left(1+\frac{x\Phi(x)}{\phi(x)}\right)$. Since, it is already shown that $h(x)+x\ge 0$, we know $\left(1+\frac{x\Phi(x)}{\phi(x)}\right)\ge 0$. Thus, $f(x)>\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}f(x)=0$. Therefore $h'(x)+1\ge0$

Comment: Note that $h(x)+x=\frac{\int_{-\infty}^x \Phi(y) dy}{\Phi(x)}$. Thus the original question is, how to show $\frac{\int_{-\infty}^x \Phi(y) dy}{\Phi(x)}$ is positive and increasing.